# Handle Home button click event using DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

**[UPDATE]**

I've changed the `activity_main.xml` and the `MainActivity.class` as follows: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html?hl=es-419), from the Android Developer Guide and now it works perfectly.

---

I'm using a `DrawerLayout` for my `MainActivity`, which contains a `FrameLayout` just to set different `Fragments` but I'm not able to handle its clicks. It works, the menu is opened and closed but I don't know how or where to manage them. This is my code:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll_main_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/lateral_menu_header" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lateral_menu_listView"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String CURRENT_FRAGMENT = "mCurrentFragment";

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayList<LateralMenuItem> lateralMenuItems;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    public ActionBar mActionBar;

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbar();
        initLateralMenu();

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    private void initLateralMenu() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, 0, 0);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();

            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lateral_menu_listView);
            if (mDrawerList != null) {
                lateralMenuItems = initLateralMenuList();

                LateralMenuListAdapter lateralMenuListAdapter = new LateralMenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, lateralMenuItems);
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(lateralMenuListAdapter);

                mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            // THIS DOESN'T WORK, I'VE DEBUGGED AND IS UNREACHABLE
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The thing is that `onOptionesItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is not working. I've also tried to set an `mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(...)`, `mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...)` and `mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()` and none of them worked.

My objective is to handle when I am in one or another `Fragment` to set the Home button as up and can override `onBackPressed()`.

Maybe the logic is different when you use the `DrawerLayout`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_logout:
            logoutDialog();
            break;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Try this

Comment: It doesn't work either. I've debugged at the switch point and it doesn't even stop there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using NavigationView with custom list view and you gave `setOnItemClickListener` to the list view not NavigationView, so the call will come to

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
```

but I am not sure where is this piece of code in your class.

For your case callback will come to `onItemClick` not onNavigationItemSelected.

If you have any question, Please let me know.

Comment: You're right, the list items are called from `onItemClick`, but I want to handle the `ActionBar`'s Home button, what is completely different.